# What is the smallest value beside 1 of a binomial with two integer values > 0?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm searching for the smallest possible value of a `binomial(a, b)` where `a >= b` and both values are greater than `0`. I calculated a few binomials and always got the result `a` as the smallest possible value. Is this always the case or just a coincidence?

Comment: You appear to be keeping $a$ fixed and letting $b$ vary.  Is that correct?

Comment: a, b both vary. What I'm trying to find out if I can choose a or b within the limitations described above so that a value smaller than a can occur.

Comment: See Zubin's answer.

Comment: The Question should be edited to reflect the condition stated in the title but not the body of the Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $a^\text{th}$ row (the top row is the $0^\text{th}$) of [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) contains all of the binomial coefficients of the form $$\binom{a}{b}$$

The smallest non-$1$ element of each row is $$\binom{a}{1}=\binom{a}{a-1}=a$$

Thus, your hypothesis is correct.

---

The smallest non-$1$ value over all pairs occurs for $a=2$:

$$\binom{2}{1}=\boxed{2}$$

Comment: What about $a \choose a$ ?

Comment: That is $1$, and OP specified non-$1$.

Comment: I see now, that misunderstood the question.